# WPF change left margin of textbox

Tags: wpf, user-interface, margin

I want to change the just the left margin of a WPF textbox via XAML:

This code obviously does not work  :

```
<TextBox Margin.Left ="0"/>
```

What would be the correct code, does anyone here know ?

Regards,
MadSeb

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522018/properties-order-in-margin/.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I can't see your code - but it would normally go like this:

```
<TextBox Margin="5 0 0 0"/>
```

First number is left, then top, then right and finally bottom margin.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply...what I want to do is to change the left to 5 but without setting the top,right,bottom to 0 !

Comment: i would use commas: Margin="0,0,0,0" it makes it easier to read

Comment: @MadSeb: The value is of type Thickness - which means it is a all-or-nothing setter. You can do it in code-behind tho.

Comment: . @MuadDib: All a matter of taste - I find commas irritating :-)

Comment: You can place the TextBlock inside a Canvas and set Canvas.Left attached property in the TextBlock. Like <canvas><TextBlock Canvas.Left="5" /> </Canvas>

Comment: @Avatar: Great idea! Should probably use a DockPanel instead, though to get the TextBox to fill - and set the Padding="5 0 0 0" on the DockPanel.